# How to share hash of hash in multithread perl

Tags: multithreading, perl, hash, share

One way to share a hash of hash is to declare every level of hashes like:

```
my %hash : shared;
$hash{test} = &share({});
```

but what if the first level keys' amount cannot be predicted or too much that you cannot declare every one.

like the code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use threads;
use threads::shared;

my %counts :shared;
my $infile = $ARGV[0];
open my $inf, "$infile";

while(my $inline = <$inf>){
    chomp($inline);
    my @entry = split(/\t/,$inline);
    my $t = threads->create('WORK',@entry)->join;
}

foreach my $i(sort {$a cmp $b} keys %counts){
    foreach my $j(sort {$a cmp $b} keys %{$counts{$i}}){
        print "$i\t$j\t$counts{$i}{$j}\n";
    }
}

sub WORK{
    my @work = @_;
    $counts{$work[0]}{$work[1]}++;
}
```

And the test set:

```
apple   pie
banana  icecream
orange  juice
mango   juice
mango   pie
mango   pie
......
```

The script will be stopped by warning you that "Invalid value for shared scalar at SOME line". So is there a way I can share both %counts and %{$counts{KEY1}}? Suppose I don't know how many and what kinds of fruit I will observe of test set column one and the output should be like:

```
apple    pie      1
banana   icecream 1
mango    juice    1
mango    pie      2
orange   juice    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, you rely on *autovivification*: Hashes and Arrays, once referenced, just spring into existence. This usually works. It does not when you `use threads` (autovivificated data structures are not shared by default). We can simply create the subhash ourself if needed. This would make your `WORK` sub

```
sub WORK{
  unless (exists $counts{$_[0]}) {
    my %anon :shared;
    $counts{$_[0]} = \%anon;
  }
  $counts{$_[0]}{$_[1]}++;
}
```

or

```
sub WORK { ($counts{$_[0]} //= do{my %a :shared; \%a})->{$_[1]}++ }
```

or similar. I also removed the rather useless copying of the `@_` array.

Do note that your example doesn't even need threading. Because you do

```
my $t = threads->create('WORK',@entry)->join;
```

this is almost exactly equivalent to

```
my $t = WORK(@entry);
```

Also, `join` returns the return value of the thread (in this case the count *before* the increment, as it is the value of the last statement), and *not* a thread object.

Comment: Thanks! I know it can be simplified, I created this example just to learn how to use multithreads in perl. but in the second solution, do you mean //= or ||=  ?

Comment: @lolibility I used `//=`. It means "assign if not defined". `$a //= $b` is the same as `$a = defined $a ? $a : $b`. It is not available in ancient perls. However, `||=` would work as well.